# How can I access my php file from javascript in my directory structure?

Tags: javascript, php, directory-structure

I have the following directory structure in my PHP project (framework: https://github.com/panique/mini)

```
application
--controller
----album.php
--libs
----s3demo.php
--model

public
--css
--img
--js
----application.js
```

In the application.js (inside js folder) I have the following code

```
    signature: {
        endpoint: "s3demo.php"
    },
```

How can I access the s3demo.php (in the libs folder) from my javascript (application.js in the js folder)? I have tested with relative path ../../application/libs/s3demo.php and even tried to go through my controller album.php but cant access the file.

s3demo.php includes access codes to my Amazon S3 account so I want to have it outside my public folder.

Any suggestion?

Edit

After I read the documentation (again) I changed the javascript to

```
signature: {
    endpoint: url + "/album/uploadImage"
},
```

And created a new function in album.php

```
public function uploadImage() {
    return APP . '/libs/s3demo.php';
}
```

But this does not work either. I think I understand routes. The javascript calls the function in album.php and the funtion return the s3demo.php. But it feels wrong to return a php-file.

Comment: Notice the `index.php` inside `/public`? That is your only entry point to the application. Read the docs at http://php-mini.com/documentation/ to work out how to use routes.

Comment: Should I add require APP . '/libs/s3demo.php'; in index.php?

Comment: No you should read the docs on "How MINI works" to understand routes.

Comment: I think a understand routes. First element names the controller, in my case “album”.  The second element names the action, the method inside that controller, in my case "uploadImage". I have updated my question.

Comment: You're right, it is wrong to return the php file. Inside that function you would use the code from s3demo.php by requiring it or using classes / functions it exposes for you.